# inspect rust traits at runtime

Tags: rust, introspection

is there a way to inpect the traits an object provides at runtime. Similar to pythons dir()? I wish to inspect the contents of a `core::str::StrSplits<'_>` and would like to be able to view the traits it implements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no facility for doing this at runtime; at compile time, however, there is, and this is what rustdoc does.

With that you can see things like the [`core::str::StrSplits` documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/str/struct.StrSplits.html) which covers the information you requested.